# UPDATE table SET with multi values

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I have spent a lot of time online trying to look for an answer but no success so I decided to post the following.
I have the following tables:

```
TABLE_1
+------------+---------------+
| child_id   | mother_id     |
+------------+---------------+
|          1 |             4 |
|          2 |             3 |
|          3 |             2 |
|          4 |             1 |
+------------+---------------+

TABLE_2
+------------+---------------+
| child_id   | mother_id     |
+------------+---------------+
|          1 |             0 |
|          2 |             0 |
|          3 |             0 |
|          4 |             0 |
+------------+---------------+
```

I would like to update the values of mother_id in my table 2 with the values of of mother_id located in my table 1.
Of course the example above could be solved doing manually:

```
UPDATE table2 SET mother_id = 1 where child_id = 4;
UPDATE table2 SET mother_id = 2 where child_id = 3;
UPDATE table2 SET mother_id = 3 where child_id = 2;
UPDATE table2 SET mother_id = 4 where child_id = 1;
```

But let's imagine I have thousand of lines to update. Is there any way to do this using select join queries (on child_id) mixed with update in order to have only a few lines of code?

Thank you.

Comment: You want table2 to match table1?

Comment: Yes, I want to update table 2 using values from table 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE
 table_2 AS t2 
 INNER JOIN table_1 AS t1 
   ON t2.child_id = t1.child_id
SET t2.mother_id = t1.mother_id;
```

You need to join the two tables based on the matching `child_id` and later set the values of `mother_id` from `table_1` to that of `table_2`.

Here's a [**demo**](http://rextester.com/live/EDPEU70929) of it

Comment: Amazing! It works. Thank you also for the demo, it really helped me to understand how the UPDATE works with JOIN.

Answer (score 2):

It is done through the inner join effectively

```
update table_2 
inner join table_1 
on table_2.child_id = table_1.child_id
set table_2.mother_id = table_1.mother_id;
```